# shouldComponentUpdate is not working when added an extra check?

Tags: reactjs, react-dom, react-component

I' am beginner in react and i was trying to make a memo application and finally the time came where i applied the weird shouldComponentUpdate method to check if the value of previous props and state are not the same and if the memo is not defined as empty.

Everything works fine but when i added that if the note is not empty the save btn stops working!

Here's my note component

```
class Note extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.edit = this.edit.bind(this)
        this.remove = this.remove.bind(this)
        this.save   = this.save.bind(this)
        this.randomBetween = this.randomBetween.bind(this)
        this.state    = {editing:false}

    }


    shouldComponentUpdate (newProps,newState){
        return (newProps.children !== this.props.children || newState !== this.state)

    }

    edit(e){
        this.setState({editing:true})
    }
    remove(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        this.props.remove(this.props.id)
    }

    save(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        var newText = this.NoteInput.value
        this.props.update(this.props.id,newText)
        this.setState({editing:false})

    }

    formDisplay(){
        return (
            <div className='note' style={this.style}>
                <form>
                <input type="text" className="note-input" ref={input => this.NoteInput = input} defaultValue = {this.props.children}></input>
                <button onClick={this.save}>save</button>
                </form> 
            </div>
        )
    }
    noteDisplay(){
        return (
            <div className="note" ref = {note => this.note = note} style={this.style}>
                <p>{this.props.children}</p>
                <span>
                    <button className="edit" onClick={this.edit}>edit</button>
                    <button className="remove" onClick={this.remove}>remove</button>
                </span>     
            </div>
        )
    }

    render() {
        return this.state.editing ? this.formDisplay() : this.noteDisplay()
    }


}
```

All of this code works fine but when  add this code to the "shouldComponentUpdate" it doesn't work

```
shouldComponentUpdate (newProps,newState){
        return ((newProps.children !== this.props.children || newState !== this.state) && newProps.children !== "")

    }
```

This basically adds an additional check which says that if the newprop.children is "" that means if the new text is empty then don't update

When i click the save button with this piece of code.Nothing happens it doesn't render the note with it's previous data like it did before.What's wrong here?

Comment: have you tried logging the values of `newProps`, `newState` and `this.props` to console inside `shouldComponentUpdate`

Comment: That condition does not make sense, you need to detect changes. Also, once `children ===` then any chance to your state won't trigger a render. Remove `newProps.children !== ""`, that has no place there. Why did you add that condition?

Comment: I know that but what i don't understand why the component state doesn't change and if i remove this it basically allows a empty string as a note!